# How to set onclicklistener in lazyadapter->getItem() and launch an activity in onClick Method

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-intent

I have two buttons 'Edit' & Delete in listview and when user click a button then i have to launch a new activity "EditActivity or DeleteActivity" for edit and delete buttons.

`public class DepartmentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements OnClickListener
{

```
int resource;
String response;
Context context;
//Initialize adapter
public DepartmentAdapter(Context _context, int resource, ArrayList<Department> items) {
    super(_context, resource, items);
    this.resource=resource;

    context = _context;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
        LinearLayout deptView;
    //Get the current Department  object
    Department dept = getItem(position);

    //Inflate the view
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        deptView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
        String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(inflater);
        vi.inflate(resource, deptView, true);
    }
    else
    {
        deptView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }
    //Get the text boxes from the listitem.xml file
    TextView id =(TextView)deptView.findViewById(R.id.Id);
    TextView sname =(TextView)deptView.findViewById(R.id.sname);
    TextView name =(TextView)deptView.findViewById(R.id.name); 
    //Assign the appropriate data from our Department object above
    id.setText(Integer.toString(dept.getID()));
    sname.setText(dept.getDepartmentShortName());
    name.setText(dept.getDepartmentName());

    Button edit = (Button)deptView.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    //del= (Button)deptListView.findViewById(R.id.del);
    ShowDepertment  d = new ShowDepertment();       

    edit.setOnClickListener(this);


}

public void onClick(View v) {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context , AddDepertment.class);
    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);        
}
```

}`

In onclick(), unable to launch activity and Getting Error:

`10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at my.mewappattendance.myAdapters.DepartmentAdapter.getView(DepartmentAdapter.java:80)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12727)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12727)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1196)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:555)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12727)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12727)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12727)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12727)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1068)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2446)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-21 13:15:11.116: E/AndroidRuntime(11718):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because when you click on button the GC is removed the Adapter class from memory, so you must add a listener to the button just by something like this :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
}
});
```

Comment: i have implemented your solution but getting same Error

Comment: Is any alternative solution for this "I have two buttons 'Edit' & Delete in listview and when user click a button then i have to launch a new activity "EditActivity or DeleteActivity" for edit and delete buttons."